# Accessing `this` within an event listener

Tags: javascript, scope, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Written in typescript, I have this:

```
export class EventDiscussionPage {
    messages: any = []
    private _channel: any;
    initChat() {
      this._channel.on('messageAdded', function(message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
      }
    }
}
```

When a message is added, I get `cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.  I guess I'm having a scope issue - how do I add the message to `this.messages`?

Comment: Try an arrow function instead: `this._channel.on('messageAdded', (message) => {`

Comment: Well dang that was quick - and it worked :).  `this._channel.on('messageAdded', message => this.messages.push(message))`.  I guess i need to dive deeper into scope and why arrow functions are different.

Please add as an answer so I can accept - thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRockwell [This book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) from Kyle Simpson may help

Comment: @ChrisRockwell, the short answer is that arrow functions don't have a `this` of their own so look for the `this` in the outer lexical environment.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a function close over, where the function closure causes the this to be reassigned, you can use an ES6 lambda.

You get something similar to

`this._channel.on('messageAdded', (message) => this.messages.push(message));`

More information about the `this` scope in Javascript can be found here [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3):

You have a scoping issue. Use context:

```
export class EventDiscussionPage {
    messages: any = []
    private _channel: any;
    initChat() {
      var ctx = this;
      this._channel.on('messageAdded', function(message) {
        ctx.messages.push(message);
      }
    }
}
```

the `this` you are referring to is the "_channel", you basically need to carry a reference from the parent to correctly call it.

You can also use the arrow function syntax to avoid this (as it will carry over the context of the parent):

```
export class EventDiscussionPage {
    messages: any = []
    private _channel: any;
    initChat() {
      this._channel.on('messageAdded',(message) => {
        this.messages.push(message);
      }
    }
}
```